# Multithreaded program that simulates a shell

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to make a Python program that will be a lot like a shell: mostly waiting for user input, occasionally displaying a message from another thread.

With that in mind I made the following example code:

```
import threading
import time

def printSomething(something="hi"):
    while True:
        print(something)
        time.sleep(2)

def takeAndPrint():
    while True:
        usr = input("Enter anything: ")
        print(usr)

thread1 = threading.Thread(printSomething())
thread2 = threading.Thread(takeAndPrint())

thread1.start()
thread2.start()
```

**What I expected to happen**

The user is prompted for input; occasionally this results in their message being output, other times the `printSomething` message prints first.

```
Enter anything:
hi
Enter anything: hello
hello
Enter anything: 
hi
```

**What actually happened**

It appears that only `printSomething` runs:

```
hi
hi
hi
```

**What do I need to do to have a continuous prompt for user input while also printing out messages from the other thread as necessary?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that Python **evaluates arguments before calling the function**. Therefore, the line:

```
thread1 = threading.Thread(printSomething())
```

is actually equivalent to:

```
_temp = printSomething()
thread1 = threading.Thread(_temp)
```

It is perhaps now clearer what is happening - the `Thread` is never created, let alone `start`ed, before the neverending `while` loop in `printSomething` begins. If you'd switched the order of creation, you'd have seen the other loop instead.

Instead, per [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread), you need to use the `target` parameter to set

> the callable object to be invoked by the `run()` method

For example:

```
 thread1 = threading.Thread(target=printSomething)
```

Note no parentheses after `printSomething` - you **do not** want to call it yet.

Comment: ok fine ... much better than my answer :P .... although maybe you shoulda saved the spoiler as a learning exercise for the user :P (+1)

Comment: Thanks for your help. If I do start `thread2` instead of `thread1` first it still does the the list of `hi`s though.

Comment: @fdsa - again, **`start` is never reached**. It doesn't matter which order you `start` them in, but which order you *assign* them in. Please re-read my answer more carefully.